# Kcal converter to grams

Tags: math

Im making an app that calculates the amount of grams of food that should be on the plate in a meal, depending on what amount of calories the user types in (and want to eat).

I already have a database that have over 2000 products which the user can search in. Let´s say the user searched potatoe. When the user searches for the potatoe and have decided that -"I want to eat **200 calories**(I got an input field for this) of potatoe" and then the program will tell the user how many **grams** the user needs to eat to get to that amount.

I can´t for my life figure out the math to do what I want. I have done something, but I can see by the result of this equation that it´s not correct.

```
x = calories in product per 100 grams (83.4 for potatoe)
y = user input of amount calories wanted
z = ?

(x / 100) * y = z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the inverse:

```
(y / x) * 100 = z
```

Answer (score 0):

for x calories (84 cal for a potato) ------->  gives 100 gram of potato.
for y (known calories                ------->  gives z (known grams of potato)?

then z = (y*100)/x         grams of potato, x and y are known, z is unknown